# Adding a newline in css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I'm looking for the simplest way to break up a collection of inline-blocked divs without resorting to extra markup (such as `br`).

I started off naively thinking that the following would do the trick except that 'four' ends up on a line of its own as well which I don't really understand.

```css
.inline {
  display:inline-block;
}

.newline {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">one</div>
<div class="inline">two</div>
<div class="inline newline">three</div>
<div class="inline">four</div>
```

I have tried solutions using :after/:before found here on Stackoverflow but these only work for me if my elements are inline instead of inline-block.

Regrettably I also need to support IE6!

**Attempt with floats**

This example below does not display properly in IE 6

```css
.inline {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F00;
}
.newline {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">one</div>
<div class="inline">two</div>
<div class="inline newline">three</div>
<div class="inline">four</div>
```

The result in IE 6

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block IE 6 does not support `inline-block` except for elements with a display of `inline` by default, so you seem to have a more fundamental problem.

Comment: The "display:block" style forces the element to be on a line of its own, not just to START a new line. That's why you were seeing the fourth item on a new line too.

Comment: What's the problem with using `<br>`? That's what it's for.

Comment: I suppose floating is out of the question? - http://jsfiddle.net/vom8dy11/1/

Comment: Is far easier for me to programmatically add a css class. It amazes me that something seemingly so simple is still an issue. I've been trawling the web for a while now and still haven't found a clear solution...

Comment: No floating would be fine but I can't get it to work in old IEs.

Comment: Don't know why...it's been supported since IE4 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: @Paulie_D - It doesn't work like we expect it to in IE6 or 7. I answered with that same example :D Run it through [Net Renderer](http://netrenderer.com/index.php). The fourth div is lined up with 1 and 2

Comment: Can't put JSFiddle through that.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Use this link exactly in netrenderer - http://jsbin.com/bemur/1/

Comment: @misterManSam indeed, only IE11 runs it correctly.

Comment: @AnthonyWebster - my example runs fine from IE8+ only IE 7 and below present weird issues. The problem is, I haven't had to deal with these issues in a decade ;)

Comment: @AnthonyWebster -  it's above, I'm using [this example here](http://jsbin.com/bemur/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks. I figured out why it wasn't working for me in IE 8+, no Doctype (duh). So at least I'll have it working in IE8+ but I still need IE 6 and 7 (regrettably that decision is out of my hands). Even a seperate css would do as I can inject different css depending on browser and version...

Comment: [Flippant]The problem, really, is that you have to support IE LTE 9.[/Flippant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE6 and other old browsers you need to add a clear line for example using this code:

```
<div class="inline">one</div>
<div class="inline">two</div>
<div class="visualClear"></div>
<div class="inline">three</div>
<div class="inline">four</div>


.inline {
     float: left;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background: #F00;
}   
.visualClear {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
}
```

I know that it isn´t very pretty but it will work for you.